# HTML form for parameters for a GET request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

From what I can see (python and Django noob here), the REST Framework allows me to show a HTML form for `POST` requests by setting `serializer_class` in my class.

For example, the code below will produce something like the last image [on this documentation page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/):

```
class BookView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookViewSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Is it possible to have a form like that shown for a `GET` request? I'd like to provide search parameters for a `GET` request (`/book.json?titleLike=django`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListCreateAPIView` (instead of `GenericAPIView`) to be able to list and create objects.

To add searching feature, please follow this section:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter